# How to set the plotting area size in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am able to set the figure size but I need to have the same size for the plots. I am saving the plots as SVG and then loading them in Latex to create a figure. I have verified that the size of all the figures is the same but as shown by the **red horizontal line** in the screenshot below, the height of the plots is not the same.

[image]

**My function to create and save plots:**

```
def plot_and_save_figure(title, X, Y, xy_min, xy_max, save_image_path):
    f = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100)
    
    plt.scatter(X, Y, alpha=0.5, label='Data Points')
    plt.plot((xy_min,xy_max), (xy_min,xy_max), 'r')
    
    plt.xlim(xy_min,xy_max)
    plt.ylim(xy_min,xy_max)
            
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'box')


    plt.savefig(save_image_path, bbox_inches='tight')

    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    
    return f
```

**Question:** How can I enforce that the drawing Width-Height of my square plots are the same?

Comment: Don't use `bbox_inches='tight'` - it trims your figures to fit all decorations, which can be subtly different depending on what you plot.

Comment: @JodyKlymak If I don't use it then, the plots have a lot of whitespaces due to which there is lot of empty whitespace among the plots in Latex.

Comment: Rather than saving the 4 plots individually and then stitching them together in Latex, can you make one matplotlib figure with 4 subplots?  Compressed layout will help with the white space between them https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html#grids-of-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes-compressed-layout

Comment: Instead of `bbox_inches="tight"`, does removing that and adding `plt.tight_layout()` before saving produce better/more consistent results?